# How to distribute closed source libraries in Dart?

Tags: dart

I am trying to distribute a library written in Dart, but reading this link https://dart.dev/guides/libraries/create-library-packages I found no mention to distributing a closed source library.

Is it possible? Is there is a way to generate something like a JAR and distributing it?

Comment: Did you find something?

Answer (score -1):

I guess the only way to achieve this is to share the complete project/library source code and then include the dependency from the local file system using path dependencies. See Dart documentation: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/dependencies#path-packages

Answer (score -1):

I've done some research and according to it there's no way at the moment.
I've created an issue in Dart lang github: https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/1119.

Then I found existing issue, but there's no update there for a while: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/37952

Answer (score -3):

There are many ways to distribute a dart/flutter package. Check the full documentation at :

https://dart.dev/tools/pub/dependencies

## 1 Distribute package via git

You can share your package via a private git repository and give others access to it. They have to update their pubspec.yaml like this and need access to the git repository:

```
name: My Project
description: Foo Bar
dependencies:
  kittens:
    git: git://github.com/munificent/kittens.git
```

## 2 Distribute package via .zip

Another way ist to wrap the package in a .zip file, share it with other people. They need to extract the .zip and update their pubscpec.yaml file like this :

```
name: My Project
description: Foo Bar
dependencies:
  kittens:
    path: /Path/To/Extracted/Zip
```

## 3 Create your own package server

Create your own server that matches the pub api or start your own server from https://github.com/dart-lang/pub_server.

```
dependencies:
  transmogrify:
    hosted:
      name: transmogrify
      url: http://your-package-server.com
      version: ^1.4.0
```

Comment: With all these ways, the entire code would be visible. It could still be under a non-open source license, so your answer is technically correct, but I think the author does not want to share the code.